# Is there any a pure clean class which support getattr and setattr in Python?

Tags: python, class, types

I use a Context class:

```
class Context(object):
    ...
```

So I can use this class to define a object which support getattr and setattr. I want to use the object to communicate between some threads.

However I think it is stupid to let the user define such a class. So I want to find out is there any a primitive type or a class from the standard library which support getattr and setattr.

I have tried the `object` class, but the object of it can not set attribute:

```
a = object()
a.b = 1

class C(object):
    ...

c = C()
c.d = 1
```

I can set `c.d = 1`, but `a.b` complains `'object' object has no attribute 'b'`。

Comment: why not just use a dictionary? or really almost any mechanism you want (including this one (that does not make much sense))

Comment: @JoranBeasley Sometime `a.b` is better than `a[b]` necessarily。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [types.SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

> A simple object subclass that provides attribute access to its namespace, as well as a meaningful repr.
>
> Unlike object, with SimpleNamespace you can add and remove attributes.

Comment: then keep doing the hacky thing you were doing before ... the great thing about programming is you can do whatever you want

Comment: How is that different than `collections.namedtuple`?

Comment: @cricket_007, If I understand correctly, `collections.namedtuple` instances don't let you add new attributes to them after the fact. You can do `x = types.SimpleNamespace(); x.foo = 23`, but you can't do `y = collections.namedtuple("thing", [])(); y.foo = 23`.

Comment: It does say in the docs "However, for a structured record type use namedtuple() instead.", but they don't seem to make that distinction about immutable instances